# Lock object in Java threads for certain period

Tags: java, multithreading

I need to implement the following scenario

- ThreadN acquires a lock
- ThreadM tries to acquire the lock and wait
- ThreadX (monitor) sees that ThreadN is holding lock too long time and releases the lock
- ThreadM acquires the lock and continue

Fate of ThreadN does not matter.

Which classes (from java.util.concurrent ?) should I use ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you can implement this based on [`Semaphore`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Semaphore.html), though you'll have to implement the monitoring functionality yourself by setting a timestamp when a lock is acquired, checking it periodically and interrupting the thread holding the lock if it's held too long.

The [`LockSupport`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/LockSupport.html) class also looks like it could help.

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you can't.

Locking in Java is cooperative - if a Thread acquires a lock on an Object you can not force it to release lock from another Thread.

All java.util.concurrent classes build upon basic Java locking features (synchronize/wait/notify) so they have no such capability.

What you should do is write ThreadN so that it releases a lock occasionally. You could do this using basic locking constructs (synchronize/wait/notify) by adding an atomic variable (boolean) that signalizes that another thread needs a lock. Then ThreadN would release the lock.

Alternatively use so higher-level java.util.concurrent class such as Lock.